# Find all directories in a directory

Tags: python

Is there a method to find all directories in a given directory? I am trying the following, which gives me an empty list:

```
[item for item in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.isdir(item)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.listdir(dir)` returns names relative to `dir`, you have to do something like:

```
[item for item in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir, item))]
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to use `os.path.join()` to join the directory to the entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
[item[0] for item in os.walk(dir)]
```